# Unable to open WampServer's config file,

Tags: php

i am trying to create image uploading in php ,when i press the upload button it shows me this error

> Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in
>   index.php file

File:

Comment: Can we see your code ?

Comment: check your path...i guess, if u have set it in relative manner than u missed the directory hierarchy somewhere!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you kept your index.php file inside a project directory instead of inside **www** under **wamp**. You must keep it exactly in **www directory**